# SF retag: "esx" and "esxi" to "vmware-esx" and "vmware-esxi"?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

At time of writing, there are questions tagged thus on ServerFault:

- 178 in "esx"
- 124 in "esxi"
- 48 in "vmware-esx"
- 45 in "vmware-esxi"
- 901 in "vmware":

  - 115 also have "esx"
  - 63 also have "esxi"
  - 17 also have "vmware-esx"
  - 16 also have "vmware-esxi"

The advice on "How to Tag":

> - favor existing popular tags
> - combine multiple words into single-words with dashes

Which is correct: leave the "esx[i]" tags because they're popular, or retag to "vmware-esx[i]" because they combine multiple words?

Is it better to have tags that combine multiple categories (and thus create new categories), or have multiple tags so that the intersections are useful? "esx" and "esxi" are both subsets of "vmware" (they're similar but distinct VMWare products), but "vmware" seems to be being used as a generic term for "virtualisation"...

Comment: esx != esxi, etc.

Comment: @John Hence nobody suggested merging the two ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged the tags according to [Farseeker's proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/sf-retag-esx-and-esxi-to-vmware-esx-and-vmware-esxi/54546#54546)

`esx` → `vmware-esx`
`esxi` → `vmware-esxi`

Comment: Please consider adding tag synonyms for these. There are already 2 questions with `[esxi]` again.

Comment: Okay, done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the correct tag is `vmware-esx[i]` - this is again where synonyms would be great

Comment: Excellent, that makes this a double retag request...

Comment: I think the correct tag structure should be. vmware-esx[i] & a synonym for esx *and* esxi.